# Fetch column names from the table it will return every column two times

Tags: php, mysql

I got this result :-

```
Parameter1
Parameter2
Parameter3
Parameter1
Parameter2
Parameter3
```

but I want result like this :-

```
Parameter1
Parameter2
Parameter3
```

**Code**

```
$query = "SELECT a.COLUMN_NAME, a.COLUMN_COMMENT FROM information_schema.COLUMNS a WHERE a.TABLE_NAME = 'telemetry_standard'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);

                    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

                        if($fetch['COLUMN_COMMENT'] != ""){
                            $myarray[] = $fetch['COLUMN_NAME'];
                            $columnvalue[] = $fetch['COLUMN_COMMENT'];
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: use DISTINCT `SELECT DISTINCT column_name`

Comment: Use group by in your query

Comment: group by may give you the right answer, but not the recommended approach

Comment: You have `telemetry_standard` in two different databases. Add `TABLE_SCHEMA` to your WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have two tables with the same name in two different databases. To work around this use the following:

```
SELECT a.COLUMN_NAME, a.COLUMN_COMMENT 
 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS a 
 WHERE 
 a.TABLE_NAME = 'telemetry_standard'
 AND a.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdatabase';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a.COLUMN_NAME, a.COLUMN_COMMENT FROM 
       information_schema.COLUMNS a WHERE a.TABLE_NAME = 'telemetry_standard' AND 
       a.COLUMN_COMMENT <> '' GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME";
```

Comment: if you are going to use aliases, use them. Moreover, why group by?